# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createToken()

Tags: laravel, api, credentials

I created API for my application using passport. I followed steps from laravel guidelines. but I cannot `createToken` and return when user register and login successfully

```
$user = User::find($id);
$token = $user->createToken('app')->accessToken;
$response['token'] = $token;
```

---

This is my user model

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Authenticatable implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, CanResetPassword;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to help with insufficient information. Have you checked if the user is valid, made the necessary imports, ran the migrations, changed the configs etc ? Chances might be you missed something.

Comment: Have you added the **Trait** `HasApiTokens` to your **User** model?

Comment: Thanks for response, I already added that trait but still not work

Comment: Is this your full code ? It seems that `$user` is an instance of `Builder` like if you would had done `$user = User::where('id', $id);`